# How does react know which state to give which component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the docs
https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

In relation to Example 1
The docs mention:

> It’s the position in the UI tree—not in the JSX markup—that matters to React!

> The App component returns a `<div>` with `<Counter />` as a first child. To React, these two counters have the same “address”: the first child of the first child of the root. This is how React matches them up between the previous and next renders, regardless of how you structure your logic.

But in Example 2

Why does the change in parent cause the state of the component to be reset? doesn't it still have the same address of "the first child of the first child of the root"?

---

Example 1

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isFancy, setIsFancy] = useState(false);
  if (isFancy) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter isFancy={true} />
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isFancy}
            onChange={e => {
              setIsFancy(e.target.checked)
            }}
          />
          Use fancy styling
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Counter isFancy={false} />
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isFancy}
          onChange={e => {
            setIsFancy(e.target.checked)
          }}
        />
        Use fancy styling
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example 2

```
export default function App() {
  const [isFancy, setIsFancy] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {isFancy ? (
        <div>
          <Counter isFancy={true} /> 
        </div>
      ) : (
        <section>
          <Counter isFancy={false} />
        </section>
      )}
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isFancy}
          onChange={e => {
            setIsFancy(e.target.checked)
          }}
        />
        Use fancy styling
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's literally what the text says happens. The result is the same hierarchy, despite the JSX looking different. React works with the virtual dom that your JSX defines, not with the JSX itself (which is also why it's so important to use `key` attributes when doing things like element generation through an array.map call)

Answer (score 0):

I think the wording used is somewhat confusing, and can lead to the wrong impression of how it works.

It's a function, the hooks are connected to the *function* and are not related to any JSX you generate. Your state comes from `useState()` and because this is associated with the *function*, it doesn't matter what JSX/HTML is generated.

> Why does the change in parent cause the state of the component to be reset? doesn't it still have the same address of "the first child of the first child of the root"?

First, it's important to think about *hierarchy and parent/child relationships* in terms of the **React Components** (the functions we were talking about above), *not* in terms of the **generated HTML/JSX**.

1. A change in the parent should not change the state of the component to be reset
2. In the examples, there is no hierarchy (since there is only one component)